# If <variable>: (Why is there no value assigned?)

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, branch, conditional-statements

Can anybody tell why is there no value assigned to `begin` after the condition at `if begin:` and just end with a colon instead? May I know what does it mean?

```
if begin:
    begin = int(begin)
    end = int(raw_input("End:"))
    print "word[", begin,":",end,"] ",
    print word[begin:end]

raw_input("\n\nPress the Enter Key to exit.")
```

Thank You!

Comment: `if begin:` checks that the variable begin has a value or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following snipped and it worked.

## Code:

```
word = "PythonWizard"
print word
begin = int(raw_input("Begin:"))
if begin:
    begin = int(begin)
    end = int(raw_input("End:"))
    print "word[", begin,":",end,"] ",
    print word[begin:end]

raw_input("\n\nPress the Enter Key to exit.")
```

## Output:

[image]